# Java String Index Out of Bound ( String Index out of Range) on line 150

Tags: java

Hi I'm a newbie with Java, and I'm trying to write a small simple text-base quiz game for one of my homework, this here is the code:

```
import java.util.* ;

class Quiz
{
   public static void main( String[] not_in_use )
   {    
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in ) ;

      int money = 0;
      char answer;
  boolean quit = false;
  int id = 0;
  int id1 = 0;
  System.out.print("\nWelcome to Haluatko Miljonääriksi?."
                    + "\nAn interactive quiz game about Finland by Khoa \"Kazkyu\" Nguyen.\n"
                    + "\nYou are given 15 multiple-choice questions."
                    + "\nEarn money and move on by choosing the right answer, final price is 1 million Euros."
                    + "\nAnswer a question by typing A, B, C, D on your keyboard."
                    + "\nType in \"save\" to use Lifesaver."
                    + "\nQuit the game and keep your earned money by typing \"exit\"."
                    + "\nYou still win with half the money you earned if you answer wrong."
                    + "\n\nPress Enter to begin: ");

   keyboard.nextLine();                 
  if ( (id <= 15) && (quit == false))
  { 
    System.out.print("\nWhat is the name of Finland in Finnish?:\n"
                     +"\nA. Suomi"
                     +"\nB. Soumi"
                     +"\nC. Suomea"
                     +"\nD. Soumea"
                     +"\n\n");
     answer  =  keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
         while (!( ( answer  ==  'A' ) || 
            ( answer  ==  'a' ) || ( answer  ==  'B' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'b' ) || ( answer  ==  'C' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'c' ) || ( answer  ==  'D' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'd' ) || ( answer  ==  'E' ) || 
            ( answer  ==  'e' ) || ( answer  ==  'S' ) || (answer == 's')))
   {
     System.out.print( "\nWrong input A,B,C,D or Exit or Save only.\n");
          answer  =  keyboard.nextLine().charAt( 0 ) ;
   }
             if (( answer == 'A') || (answer == 'a'))
               {
                money = money + 200;
                id = id + 1;
                System.out.print ( "\nCorrected, you earned " + money + " Euros\n" );
               }
             else if (( answer == 'B') || (answer == 'b') || (answer == 'C') || (answer == 'c')
             || ( answer == 'D') || (answer == 'd'))
               {
                System.out.print ( "\nWrong, you lose, no money for you\n"
                                   +"Game over, good luck next time\n");
                quit = true;
               }
             else if ((answer == 'E') || (answer == 'e'))
               {
                System.out.print ("\nYou choose to quit, your money is: " + money + " Euros"
                                  +"\nGood luck next time\n");
                quit = true;                    
               } 

             else if ((answer == 'S') || (answer == 's'))
               {
                id1 = id1 + 1;
                System.out.print ("\nPlease choose your life saver:"
                                  +"\nType 1 for \"Skip and get point\""
                                  +"\nType 2 for \"Surf Wikipedia for answer\", Warning: Very Random"
                                  +"\nType 3 for \"Asked Jere, Michal, Jaska, Marios for help\", Warning: Very Random"
                                  +"\n\n");
                           int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                               if (choice == 1)
                                {
                                 money = money + 200;
                                 id = id + 1;
                                 answer
                                 System.out.print ("\nQuestion Skipped, earn " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                }
                               if ( choice == 2 )
                                {
                                 Random rand = new Random();
                                 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                                 if (randomNum == 1)
                                 {
                                  money = money + 200;
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is A, right answer, ");
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 2)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is B ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 3)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is C ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 4)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is D ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                }
                               if (choice == 3)
                                {
                                 Random rand1 = new Random();
                                 int randomNum1 = rand1.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                                  if (randomNum1 == 1)
                                   {
                                    money = money + 200;
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou asked Jere and got the answer: A.\n"
                                                    +"Right answer, " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                   }
                                  if (randomNum1 == 2)
                                   {
                                    money = money + 200;
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou asked Michal and got the answer: A.\n"
                                                    +"Right answer, " + money + " Euros.\n"); 
                                   }
                                  if ( randomNum1 == 3)
                                   {
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou called Jaska and recieved a \"Whatever, I like milk, why not\" for an answer."
                                                    + "\nYou answered \"Whatever, I like milk, why not\", Wrong answer."
                                                    + "\nGame over, You earn " + money + " Euro.\n");
                                    quit = true;
                                    }
                                  if ( randomNum1 == 4)
                                  {
                                    System.out.print ("You called Marios and he gave you this answer:\n"
                                                    + "\nAyy Lmao, get rekt m8, inb4 4chan raid."
                                                    + "\nYou don't know what the fuck it mean."
                                                    + "\nSo you quit with " + money + " Euros in your pocket.\n");
                                   quit = true;
                                   }
                                 } 

               }
   }
   if ( (id <= 15) && (quit == false))
  { 
    System.out.print("\nWhen is the Finnish's Independence Day?:\n"
                     +"\nA. 12th of December"
                     +"\nB. 25th of December"
                     +"\nC. 6th of December"
                     +"\nD. 31th of December"
                    +"\n\n");
     ****\\line 150 THIS IS LINE 150 WHERE IT HAPPEN\\
         answer  =  keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);**** 
         while (!( ( answer  ==  'A' ) || 
            ( answer  ==  'a' ) || ( answer  ==  'B' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'b' ) || ( answer  ==  'C' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'c' ) || ( answer  ==  'D' ) ||
            ( answer  ==  'd' ) || ( answer  ==  'E' ) || 
            ( answer  ==  'e' ) || ( answer  ==  'S' ) || (answer == 's')))
   {
     System.out.print( "\nWrong input A,B,C,D or Exit or Save only.\n");
          answer  =  keyboard.nextLine().charAt( 0 ) ;
   }
             if (( answer == 'C') || (answer == 'c'))
               {
                money = money + 250;
                id = id + 1;
                System.out.print ( "\nCorrected, you earned " + money + " Euros\n" );
               }
             else if (( answer == 'B') || (answer == 'b') || (answer == 'A') || (answer == 'a')
             || ( answer == 'D') || (answer == 'd'))
               {
                money = money / 2;
                System.out.print ( "\nWrong, you lose, your money is " + money + " Euros\n"
                                   +"Game over, good luck next time\n");
                quit = true;
               }
             else if ((answer == 'E') || (answer == 'e'))
               {
                System.out.print ("\nYou choose to quit, your money is: " + money + " Euros"
                                  +"\nGood luck next time\n");
                quit = true;                    
               } 

             else if ((answer == 'S') || (answer == 's'))
               {
                id1 = id1 + 1;
                System.out.print ("\nPlease choose your life saver:"
                                  +"\nType 1 for \"Skip and get point\""
                                  +"\nType 2 for \"Surf Wikipedia for answer\", Warning: Very Random"
                                  +"\nType 3 for \"Asked Jere, Michal, Jaska, Marios for help\", Warning: Very Random"
                                  +"\n\n");
                           int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                               if (choice == 1)
                                {
                                 money = money + 250;
                                 id = id + 1;
                                 System.out.print ("\nQuestion Skipped, earn " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                }
                               if ( choice == 2 )
                                {
                                 Random rand = new Random();
                                 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                                 if (randomNum == 1)
                                 {
                                  money = money + 250;
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is C, right answer, ");
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 2)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is B ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 3)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is A ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (randomNum == 4)
                                 {
                                  System.out.print ("\nWiki said answer is D ,wrong answer, Game over.\n"
                                                    +"You earned " + money + "Euros.\n");
                                  quit = true;
                                 }
                                }
                               if (choice == 3)
                                {
                                 Random rand1 = new Random();
                                 int randomNum1 = rand1.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                                  if (randomNum1 == 1)
                                   {
                                    money = money + 200;
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou asked Jere and got the answer: C.\n"
                                                    +"Right answer, " + money + " Euros.\n");
                                   }
                                  if (randomNum1 == 2)
                                   {
                                    money = money + 200;
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou asked Michal and got the answer: C.\n"
                                                    +"Right answer, " + money + " Euros.\n"); 
                                   }
                                  if ( randomNum1 == 3)
                                   {
                                    System.out.print ("\nYou called Jaska and recieved a \"Whatever, I like milk, why not\" for an answer."
                                                    + "\nYou answered \"Whatever, I like milk, why not\", Wrong answer."
                                                    + "\nGame over, You earn " + money + " Euro.\n");
                                    quit = true;
                                    }
                                  if ( randomNum1 == 4)
                                  {
                                    System.out.print ("You called Marios and he gave you this answer:\n"
                                                    + "\nAyy Lmao, get rekt m8, inb4 4chan raid."
                                                    + "\nYou don't know what the fuck it mean."
                                                    + "\nSo you quit with " + money + " Euros in your pocket.\n");
                                   quit = true;
                                   }
                                 } 

               }                  
  }
```

}
}

Everything seem to work fine except when I type in s to use the lifesaver, after choosing 1, it will skip the question like I want it to, but it also give me an Index out of bound error, and it say it's on line 150, I'm so confuse with this, everyother input work fine.

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and point out the place where the exception occurst?

Comment: You need to point out _where_ the exception happens. No one wants to look through a 250 line homework dump.

Comment: What's line 150? It's a lot of code to look through.

Comment: How can I point it out? Noobs to asking question as well

Comment: Maybe put a comment above the line or only post the relevant code.

Comment: I have try my best to point out where line 150 is by putting a comment above it

Comment: your missing a semi colon after answer plus just saying answer does nothing.(your first if statement doesn't make sense as it cannot be false)

Comment: 4-1 is three it's silly to put that in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `keyboard.nextLine()` is an empty string, which is why it throws an exception.

The reason it is empty is because after reading the integer from the user, there is still a newline character in the buffer, which causes problems.

The easiest way to fix it (tested) is to get the integer from the user like so:

```
System.out.print("\nPlease choose your life saver:"
             +"\nType 1 for \"Skip and get point\""
             +"\nType 2 for \"Surf Wikipedia for answer\", Warning: Very Random"
             +"\nType 3 for \"Asked Jere, Michal, Jaska, Marios for help\", Warning: Very Random"
             +"\n\n");

             //Modify this line right here like so.
             int choice = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

This will stop the newline from being in the buffer, which solves all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

If `answer = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0)` throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` the only possibility is that `keyboard.nextLine()` returns an empty string.

Comment: I'm not sure i can understand this since I'm a noob, can you be more specific with instruction? Like I said every other input work fine except when I type in s and then type in 1

Comment: `keyboard.nextLine()` returns an empty string (`""`). Calling `charAt(0)` on an empty string (Like so: `"".charAt(0)`) throws an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

`keyboard.nextLine()` returns an Empty string (a string with 0 characters - `""`.
You can check it by doing `System.out.println(keyboard.nextLine().length());`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the livesaver, there is no keyboard input, so `keyboard.nextLine()` is just an empty String. Since it is empty, it has no char at index 0. You have to implement some logic that skips the scanning for keyborad input part when you use a livesaver.

Answer (score 0):

in option 1 you have

```
  answer
```

no semicolon or anything it should tell you this in your compliler i have no idea why it didn't, it bugs out after that naturaly.